# How to read from InputStream in spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I have an **InputStream** coming from the source and want to read the data using Spark.

How to do that?

Comment: Probably, to have some hints, you can refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490941/spark-read-an-inputstream-instead-of-file

Comment: Is it continuous stream or is limited? Do you want to use `read` or `readStream`?

Comment: is a limited stream.